# PlaceholderColor not set to PlaceHolderLabel for UITextfield in ios13

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11

**self.setValue(placeHolderColor, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")**

in ios13 its crashed.how to set placeholderColor to placeholderLabel in swift5 for ios13 in xcode11.

Comment: Isn't that a PRIVATE API? So it's normal? No one said that it wouldn't break one day. Instead use `attributedPlaceholder` which can have a "textColor"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `color` using `attributedPlaceholder` as below,

```
let colorAttrbs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes: colorAttrbs)
```

Comment: Works for me too